# Google Maps failed to save offline maps on Lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, google-maps, offline-map

I'm using Nexus 5 32GB, Android 5.0.1. I'm trying to save maps offline, but it's showing me an error whenever I try to save.

It seems the issue is on external storage; it's not writable. The issue started when I used TWRP Updater from Google Play Store, and it added an SD card write patch. How to fix this?

Below is screenshot of error

[image: Error on Google Maps]

Comment: It seems my sdcard issue, its not writable. Im using nexus 5 32gb

Comment: According to your comment (remember, you always can and should [edit] your question to include additional details), and the fact it's a Nexus device (no external SD), the most likely reason is the "sdcard write patch" mentioned. You might check with them for a fix (e.g. how to revert that patch).

Comment: OK, let's be a little "analytic". Try a logcat while forcing this error. With some luck it reveals the culprit in a way that makes it fixable. (see our [logging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) in case you're unfamiliar with that). Then please [edit] your question with your findings. If you need to post a larger piece of log, you can link to a pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was sdcard permission issue.

I had to flash 5.0 and then 5.0.1 again from fastboot. everything works fine now.